Issue with JWT signature generation in C#
I'm not really skilled in C# but I need to create a code snippet for another software that gets events from a Google Calendar. This software is very limited in the library collection so I can use only a few of them (no JWT libraries)
I'm manually creating it but when I check it on https://jwt.io I always get invalid signature, can't really understand what I'm doing wrong. I can't understand if the issue is in the key formatting or if I'm messing with the creation of the JWT.
p.s. you can safely ignore if the usage of classes/main is wrong, I'll just use a single function in the software so I added some main/class just to try it on Visual Studio.
This is the actual code that I'm trying:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static async Task<string> CheckEventAtCurrentTime()
    {
        // Define service account details
        string serviceAccountEmail = "my@googleserviceaccount.com";
        string privateKey = @"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
        my
        private
        key
        -----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

        string tokenUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
        string scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

        // Create the JWT header
        var header = new { alg = "RS256", typ = "JWT" };
        string headerEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header)))
                                    .TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');

        // Create the JWT payload
        long iat = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        long exp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeSeconds(); // Token expires in 1 hour

        var payload = new
        {
            iss = serviceAccountEmail,
            scope = scope,
            aud = tokenUrl,
            exp = exp,
            iat = iat
        };
        string payloadEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload)))
                                    .TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');

        // Concatenate header and payload
        string unsignedToken = $"{headerEncoded}.{payloadEncoded}";
        Console.WriteLine($"Unsigned JWT: {unsignedToken}");

        // Extract the Base64 part of the PEM
        string extractedPrivateKey = privateKey
            .Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");

        // Remove any non-base64 characters (newlines, etc.)
        extractedPrivateKey = Regex.Replace(extractedPrivateKey, @"\s+", ""); // Removes all whitespace, newlines, etc.

        // Decode the Base64 private key
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(extractedPrivateKey);

        // Import the key into an RSA object
        using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKeyBytes), out _);

            // Create the RSA signature
            byte[] signedBytes = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedToken), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            string signedToken = Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes)
                                        .TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');

            // The final JWT
            string jwt = $"{unsignedToken}.{signedToken}";

            Console.WriteLine($"Generated JWT: {jwt}");

            // Request OAuth2 token
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("assertion", jwt)
                });

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenUrl, requestBody);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return "1"; // API call failed
                }

                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                string accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;

                // Set the calendar ID and time range
                string calendarId = "mycalendarID";
                DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                DateTime endTime = startTime.AddMinutes(1); // Check for events in the next minute

                // Check for events
                string eventsUrl = $"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events?timeMin={startTime:o}&timeMax={endTime:o}&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime";
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                var eventsResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(eventsUrl);

                if (!eventsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return "1"; // API call failed
                }

                var eventsBody = await eventsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(eventsBody);

                if (events.items.Count == 0)
                {
                    return "2"; // No event
                }

                // There's an event
                string eventTitle = events.items[0].summary;
                return eventTitle; // Return the event title
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Call the method to check the event
        string result = await CheckEventAtCurrentTime();

        // If result is a string, it's the event title; otherwise, it's an error code
        if (int.TryParse(result, out int errorCode))
        {
            // Handle error codes
            Console.WriteLine($"Error code: {errorCode}");
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle event found
            Console.WriteLine($"Event: {result}");
        }
    }
}


edit:
This is the JWT generated by the code:
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJpZC1jeC1obnBAY3gtaG5wLWRlbW8uaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvY2FsZW5kYXIucmVhZG9ubHkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoMi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTcyNjEyOTI1NywiaWF0IjoxNzI2MTI1NjU3fQ.FYAZeCZl8qbI9hE3xlTWl2DP6_rxazGzQoE9E9DHEaWVp_9HQHoN-sqZ3yX3stV17GqZ2gErE0AMkb_2SJF73ThlrxtJOFbMf2nOlOSHZJKLbKFlWtfO7Wd-4gXrMJXLtAROCrVhm7Wen5__6ga3l1ez_lV1aRWRatNbtk-zBkR0x-RWZbxZc2LMVGV_kAiXAORGWFO_unH6EQTG-n5ZckVKGjRm4MhxGx5hnMr46zchuc30N_N0bT7j1h4S4P_ignFT3dUllVlQQFNYKOPTWOm4qMozro_43PelKSjbkmhqHfgHxDw70IbBxTXcY4P8eiiT9dYzmmiqz27fKh8A0Q

And this is the public key:
edit2: found the correct key, the issue was the public key from Google Cloud that I had to retrieve via gcloud shell

Two remarks: 1.) invalid signature  - the typical problem is that people don't provide a key, so jwt.io can't verify the signature and as long as it not verified it's considered invalid. So you just have to paste the public key into the input field in the right column under VERIFY SIGNATURE. 2.) As you didn't show the token and the public key in the question, I can't help here to see if it's just the problem mentioned above or something more severe.

Hi @jps and thanks for your reply! I've read about the signature on another post, I tried it but it doesn't really work. I add the token and the key in the main post

Where does this public key come from? It doesn't look correct to me, it's very short and hex encoded.. You must use the public key that matches the private key that was used to sign the token. The token header says RS256 for which a public key would look like the example shown in this answer

@PaoloConcari you are limited to use library agree, why dont you look at source code of the JWT libraries out there and reuse the code, why re-inventing wheel

@jps thanks, that was the issue. I got misguided by the Google Cloud documentation and used the key ID instead of the public key. I tried with both keys and got the signature verified! Thank you very much for your help

@PaoloConcari you're welcome.
